В предложении нужно тире или двоеточие, почему?
Что сильнее – любовь или ненависть?

Правильно: ЧтО сильнее — любовь или нЕнависть?
Пояснение

Обычно в этих случаях ориентируются на правило Розенталя:
6. Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается 
при обособлении пояснительных и уточняющих членов 
предложения: Это означало одно (: —) нужно расстаться; 
Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, 
десять?; Потом началось главное (: —) поиски, нащупывание 
новых путей исследования; Кончался их разговор всегда 
одним и тем же (: —) ссорой; Сколько мне тогда было (: —) 
девятнадцать или  двадцать?; Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) 
в среду или в четверг.


Здесь я вижу только присоединительный вариант с тире по расстановке ударений. Ударением мы выделяем вопросительное местоимение ЧТО, а также ударением выделено обособленное сочетание  "любовь или ненависть", которое при наличии одиночного союза ИЛИ рассматривается как единая конструкция.

При постановке пояснительного двоеточия обычно делается подчеркнутая  пауза (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю о дальнейшем раскрытии темы), но здесь этого нет. Пауза короче и соответствует присоединительному тире.



Sharon, всё отлично, только вот ударением можно выделить и "сильнее", как смысловой центр вопроса. То есть оба первых слова имеют равноправную значимость. В случае ударения на "что" высота голоса снижается сразу после первого слога фразы, во втором случае -- восходяще-нисходящая мелодия.

О, какие люди! А  на вас как бы не рассчитывала)) Как раз подумала, Александра нет, критиковать меня в этой теме  некому — что хочу, то и говорю...)  Впрочем, возражать на этот раз не буду)  // К тому же с вопросительной интонацией не все так просто:  там повышение голоса  в конце предложения, а что в середине  не так важно.  Но интонационного предупреждения нет однозначно, поэтому это явное присоединение (с пояснительным  значением).

А в повествовательном предложении  для двоеточия и тире интонация в обоих случаях нисходяще-нисходящая.  Восходяще-нисходящая мелодия — для разделительного тире: Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил.  Проверено по Кустовой.

И с вопросит. интонацией, и с повествовательной, и с тире, и с двоеточием -- во второй фразе тоже восходяще-нисходящее: самый высокий слог -- "бовь", "ненависть" послогово уходит в тьму.

Но если только во тьму)  Надо сказать, что вы заметно изменились — ни тени сомнения  в истинности своих слов. Тоже забавно)  Люблю наблюдать характеры людей — можно так сказать?  // По теме могу только добавить, что в фонетике существуют такие послоговые схемы, но Кустова анализирует только стык фраз. Я тоже считаю, что для практических целей этого достаточно.  И на всякий случай сверяю с ней свои ответы.  Она называет вид отношений по семантике и соответствующее движение тона.  У нее при пояснении и присоединении тон нисходяще-нисходящий.

Кстати, рада вас видеть.  У нас с форума уходят по-английски и насовсем, то есть не прощаясь.  О некоторых участниках я до сих пор жалею.

Я хотел сейчас исправить предыдущий комментарий, но допишу здесь. Я имел в виду, что вопросительная интонация с повышением тона уходит не в конец второй фразы, а делается на первом слове (в нашем случае). Полностью нисходящая мелодия может быть только тогда, когда первое слово произносится с ударением на первый слог, а у нас "любовь" второслогоударенная.

К сожалению, у меня нет проверенных схем для вопросительной интонации, мне нечего вам возразить.  Поискать можно, но для практики в этом нет необходимости.

Вспомнил наши первые переписки, и там вы говорили что-то по поводу сомнений в себе... Если утрированно, то смысл такой: "А ты и ляпай. Но ляпай уверенно. У них это называется эксцентричностью".

Ляпай уверенно? Я не помню, но, наверное, так и надо. А у кого у них? Эксцентричность - смещение точки сборки/восприятия мира у некоторых людей.

Это из фильма "Москва слезам не верит". Только в этом моменте так: "Тогда это называется точкой зрения". А эксцентичностью назвали бы они (московская интеллигенция) грубость Людмилы. :)) "Вот я грубая, правда? А у них это называется эксцентричностью".

Я вчера на форуме разбирал текст для ЕГЭ  Водолазкина о Д.Лихачеве и его отношении к языку, и мне показалось, что у них обоих что-то с центрами не в порядке. Очень странный текст)  О том, то надо писать просто, очень просто (примитивно,что ли?)  "Честно говоря" им не понравилось, жеманство это.  Бытие определяет сознание или наоборот?  И т.д.

Об интонации. Могу рассказать, как слышу. Повышение голоса на "что", дальше очень коротко "сильнее" на том же уровне, без понижения тона. Потом пауза и повышение в конце фразы.  // А можно повысить тон на "сильнее", тогда это ударная позиция.

@Sharon, присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

@Серж, спасибо, мне всегда интересно ваше мнение.

Интересно сравнить: Что же все-таки сильнее: любовь или ненависть? Распространение первой части делает возможным интонационное предупреждение (неполное понижение тона со значительно увеличенной паузой).

А поставьте запятую, простенько и со вкусом. А Розенталь пока отдохнёт.

Можно и так, Розенталь разрешает. Простенько, да, но нужно, чтобы контекст соответствовал. Вот, к примеру, неторопливый разговор: Любовь, ненависть...чем -то они похожи. Вы никогда не думали о том, что сильнее, любовь или ненависть?
